# How can I remove '(1i)' and '_1i' from a string using jquery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, gsub

How can I change `form[field][date(1i)]` to `form[field][date]` and `form_field_date_1i` to `form_field_date` using jquery?

I have a date select field in a Rails 4 app.

If javascript is disabled, these are rendered as 3 select fields (year, month, date).

If javascript is enabled, I'm using [Bootstrap 3 Datepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and redrawing the select fields as a text input usng jquery.

I'm trying to write a short jquery function that applies the datepicker based on a select's class. To draw the text input and ensure the form will submit to the right place, I need to set the name and id values.

I can pull these from the original select, but they are in the format

`name='form[field][date(1i)]' id='form_field_date_1i'`

Is there something like a gsub for jquery that will remove the `(1i)` and `_1i`?

Comment: you can use `replace` in jquery

Comment: refer to this http://jsfiddle.net/NJDJD/143/

Comment: Thanks sontya. your jsfiddle is leaving the brackets. how would I also remove the brackets?

Comment: To remove the parentheses you'd escape them in the regex, or pass a string instead of a regex: `"(1i)" or /\(1i\)/`.  But are you sure you're solving the right problem?  Instead of starting with a date select and replacing it with a text field, couldn't you just use a text (or HTML5 date) field and validate the input, so users with JS disabled would be directed to enter a properly formatted date, e.g. "10/10/2010"?  And how likely is it that JS is disabled?  Having JS enabled is far more common in the wild, shouldn't you cater to that instead of rewriting a form for the majority of the users?

Comment: jQuery !== JavaScript

Comment: @numbers1311407, thanks for this comment, you make a good point. Ideally I would like to display date selects for users on touch enabled devices (to make use of native controls), a validated text field if js is disabled, and a text field with datepicker if js is enabled. I'm having trouble working out (a) which should be the default, and (b) how to mix this together with Rails form helpers to achieve the desired result. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can user `replace` which similar to `gsub`

```
name='form[field][date(1i)]'

name.replace(/(1i)/g, "").replace(/\(|\)/g, "");

name2 = `form_field_date_1i`

name2.replace(/_1i/g, "");
```

See this demo fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/NJDJD/144/)